# Conversion from type 'JArray' to useable object

Tags: json, vb.net

I get the below info back from a web API.  I do not understand how the columns can be aligned with the data.

In columns the is "ID" that is equal to 1 from the data. or "CODE" is equal to "189280609".  I will create a class that has properties that are listed in columns and want to know how to fill the properties of the class with the info listed in "Data"

I know this may be too open of a question but not sure where to start.

```
[{"Key":{"Configs":[],"Description":"OK","StatusNumber":0},"Value":[{"columns":["ID","CODE","MODEL","TYPE","ChannelCount","NAME","Description","Enabled","Battery","Temperature","LastUpdateConfig","SignalStrenght","FirmwareVersion"],"data":[[1,"189280609","EINAHR",11,3,"Spindle Sensor 1 ","High Range Accelerometer",1,-1,-1000,"2022\/07\/01 07:59:37",0,0]],"disposedValue":false,"errorMessage":null,"id":"1"}]}]
```

```
Dim nodelist As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object)) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object)))(resString)
Dim nodelist2 As List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object)) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Dictionary(Of String, Object)))(nodelist(0).Item("Value").ToString)
```

**Edit:** I have created the class using paste Special as suggested in the below comment.  When I try to Deserialise I get an error.

```
Dim objResponse1 As List(Of Class1) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Class1))(nodelist(0).Item("Value").ToString)
```

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'Phantom.Class1' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
> Path '[0].columns', line 3, position 16.

Comment: You could use the Paste Special>Paste Json as classes to build a fully defined class for your return json.  Then Deserialise it to a List of that class

Comment: Thank you This helps in creating the class.  Very useful.  I am having issues now with Deserialise of the json array.

Comment: Show the updated code?

Comment: Code also updated above.

Dim objResponse1 As List(Of Class1) = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Class1))(nodelist(0).Item("Value").ToString)